# windows different size on different platforms

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, padding, pyinstaller

I'm working on a simple app (.exe) to communicate with my PLC via Python/PC. So far everything is working fine and I'm aware Tkinter will use default widgets from OS(native widgets), except application (GUI) looks different on win7/win10. Problem is large 'blank' space on the right part of the window (have 6 windows, same problem on all, same blank area, same size). I'm not sure why this happens. Is there a way to reduce it or remove it completely? Is it a problem with padding?

I use Python 2.7, Tkinter 8.5, Pyinstaller. You can check images on the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l4ildtqp5ldq0ds/AADzmEzvbRHiwr2XrpfBUYupa?dl=0).

```py
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import pandas as pd
import tkFileDialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
from ttk import *
import xlrd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, landscape
def resource_path(relative_path):
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
fname = None
excelfile = str(None)
naziv = str(None)
lokacija = str(None)
lokacija1 = str(None)
brojredova = int(0)
X = int(0)
Y = int(0)
odabrano = str(1)
odabrano1 = str(1)
rh1 = "No"
rh2 = "No"
rh3 = "No"
ch1 = "No"
ch2 = "No"
def osnovni_prozor():
    window.deiconify()

def spec_paneli():
    window.withdraw()
    global X, Y, odabrano, odabrano1
    sub2 = Toplevel(window)
    sub2.title("Panels")
    X = window.winfo_x()
    Y = window.winfo_y()
    x = X
    y = Y
    sub2.geometry("800x875")
    sub2.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
    sub2.configure(background='white')
    sub2.resizable(width=False, height=False)


    noteStyler = Style()

    noteStyler.configure("TNotebook", borderwidth=0)
    noteStyler.configure("TNotebook.Tab", background='white', foreground="black", lightcolor='red', borderwidth=0)
    noteStyler.configure("TFrame", background='white', foreground='white', borderwidth=0)

    s1 = Style()
    s1.configure('Wild.TLabel', background='white', foreground='black')

    sub2.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=25)

    note = Notebook(sub2)
    tab1 = Frame(note)
    tab2 = Frame(note)
    tab3 = Frame(note)
    tab4 = Frame(note)
    note.add(tab1, text=' General ')
    note.add(tab2, text='Cable casing')
    note.add(tab3, text='Reinforcement')
    note.add(tab4, text=' Profiles ')
    note.pack(expand=1, fill='both')


    frame1 = Frame(tab1)
    frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="n")

    frame1.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=20)

    lbl1 = Label(frame1, text='Panel width', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl1.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=35, pady=8, sticky=W)
    lbl2 = Label(frame1, text='Panel height', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl2.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=35, pady=8, sticky=W)
    lbl3 = Label(frame1, text='Panel thickness', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl3.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=35, pady=8, sticky=W)
    lbl4 = Label(frame1, text='Type of panel', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl4.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=35, pady=8, sticky=W)
    lbl5 = Label(frame1, text='Filling', anchor="e", style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl5.grid(column=0, row=10, padx=35, pady=8, sticky=W)
    lbl6 = Label(frame1, text='Framework', anchor="e", style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl6.grid(column=0, row=11, padx=35, pady=8, sticky=W)
    lbl7 = Label(frame1, text='Opening', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl7.grid(column=0, row=14, padx=35, pady=8, sticky=W)
    lbl8 = Label(frame1, text='Count', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl8.grid(column=0, row=13, padx=35, pady=8, sticky=W)
    lbl10 = Label(frame1, text='Rivets', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl10.grid(column=0, row=12, padx=35, pady=8, sticky=W)
    lbl11 = Label(frame1, text='Sheet 1 material', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl11.grid(column=0, row=6, padx=35, pady=8, sticky=W)
    lbl12 = Label(frame1, text='Sheet 2 material', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl12.grid(column=0, row=7, padx=35, pady=8, sticky=W)
    lbl13 = Label(frame1, text='Sheet 1 color', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl13.grid(column=0, row=8, padx=35, pady=8, sticky=W)
    lbl14 = Label(frame1, text='Sheet 2 color', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl14.grid(column=0, row=9, padx=35, pady=8, sticky=W)


    txt1 = Entry(frame1, width=10, justify='center')
    txt1.grid(column=1, row=2)
    txt1.focus()
    txt2 = Entry(frame1, width=10, justify='center')
    txt2.grid(column=1, row=3)

    combo1 = Combobox(frame1, state="readonly")
    combo1['values'] = ("42mm", "62mm", "82mm")
    combo1.current(0)  # set the selected item
    combo1.grid(column=1, row=4)

    combo2 = Combobox(frame1, state="readonly")
    combo2['values'] = ("Wall panel", "Ceiling panel", "Special")
    combo2.current(0)  # set the selected item
    combo2.grid(column=1, row=5)

    combo3 = Combobox(frame1, state="readonly")
    combo3['values'] = ("Rockwool", "ALU honeycomb", "Other", "None")
    combo3.current(0)  # set the selected item
    combo3.grid(column=1, row=10)

    combo4 = Combobox(frame1, state="readonly")
    combo4['values'] = ("Aluminum", "Galvanised steel", "Other", "None")
    combo4.current(0)  # set the selected item
    combo4.grid(column=1, row=11)

    txt3 = Entry(frame1, width=10, justify='center')
    txt3.grid(column=1, row=13)
    txt4 = Entry(frame1, width=10, justify='center')
    txt4.grid(column=1, row=8)
    txt5 = Entry(frame1, width=10, justify='center')
    txt5.grid(column=1, row=9)

    combo6 = Combobox(frame1, state="readonly")
    combo6['values'] = ("None", "1S Bottom", "1S Top", "Both")
    combo6.current(0)  # set the selected item
    combo6.grid(column=1, row=12)

    combo7 = Combobox(frame1, state="readonly")
    combo7['values'] = ("Aluminum", "Galvanised steel", "Stainless steel")
    combo7.current(0)  # set the selected item
    combo7.grid(column=1, row=6)

    combo8 = Combobox(frame1, state="readonly")
    combo8['values'] = ("Aluminum", "Galvanised steel", "Stainless steel", "None")
    combo8.current(0)  # set the selected item
    combo8.grid(column=1, row=7)


    frame3 = Frame(frame1)
    frame3.grid(row=15, column=0, sticky="n", columnspan=2)

    frame3.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=20)

    lbl31 = Label(frame3, text='R X1', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl32 = Label(frame3, text='R Y1', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl33 = Label(frame3, text='R A1', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl34 = Label(frame3, text='R B1', style='Wild.TLabel')
    txt31 = Entry(frame3, width=5)
    txt32 = Entry(frame3, width=5)
    txt33 = Entry(frame3, width=5)
    txt34 = Entry(frame3, width=5)

    lbl51 = Label(frame3, text='C X1', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl52 = Label(frame3, text='C Y1', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl53 = Label(frame3, text=u'C \u03A61', style='Wild.TLabel')
    txt51 = Entry(frame3, width=5)
    txt52 = Entry(frame3, width=5)
    txt53 = Entry(frame3, width=5)


    frame3.grid_rowconfigure(3, minsize=10)

    lbl35 = Label(frame3, text='R X2', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl36 = Label(frame3, text='R Y2', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl37 = Label(frame3, text='R A2', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl38 = Label(frame3, text='R B2', style='Wild.TLabel')
    txt39 = Entry(frame3, width=5)
    txt40 = Entry(frame3, width=5)
    txt41 = Entry(frame3, width=5)
    txt42 = Entry(frame3, width=5)

    lbl54 = Label(frame3, text='C X2', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl55 = Label(frame3, text='C Y2', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl56 = Label(frame3, text=u'C \u03A62', style='Wild.TLabel')
    txt54 = Entry(frame3, width=5)
    txt55 = Entry(frame3, width=5)
    txt56 = Entry(frame3, width=5)

    frame3.grid_rowconfigure(6, minsize=10)

    lbl43 = Label(frame3, text='R X3', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl44 = Label(frame3, text='R Y3', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl45 = Label(frame3, text='R A3', style='Wild.TLabel')
    lbl46 = Label(frame3, text='R B3', style='Wild.TLabel')
    txt47 = Entry(frame3, width=5)
    txt48 = Entry(frame3, width=5)
    txt49 = Entry(frame3, width=5)
    txt50 = Entry(frame3, width=5)


    canvasm = Canvas(tab1, width=375, height=770, background='white', highlightthickness=1, relief = RAISED)
    canvasm.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=28, pady=12)


    frame2 = Frame(tab1)
    frame2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="n")

    frame2.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=3)

    frame4 = Frame(tab1)
    frame4.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

    def zatvori_ovaj():
        sub2.destroy()

    broButton5 = Button(master=frame4, text='Back', style='Wild.TButton', width=8, command=lambda:[osnovni_prozor(),zatvori_ovaj()])
    broButton5.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=35, pady=2, sticky="w")

    broButton1 = Button(master=frame2, text='Show', style='Wild.TButton', width=8)
    broButton1.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=8, pady=2)
    broButton2 = Button(master=frame2, text='Folder', style='Wild.TButton', width=8)
    broButton2.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=8, pady=2)
    broButton3 = Button(master=frame2, text='Excel', style='Wild.TButton', width=8)
    broButton3.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=8, pady=2)
    broButton4 = Button(master=frame2, text='PDF', style='Wild.TButton', width=8)
    broButton4.grid(column=3, row=1, padx=8, pady=2)

    mainloop()

window = Tk()
s1 = Style()
s1.configure('Wild.TLabel', background='white', foreground='black')
s2 = Style()
s2.configure('Wild.TRadiobutton', background='white', foreground='black')
s3 = Style()
s3.configure('Wild.TButton', background='white', foreground='black')
w = 800
h = 850
window.wm_title("Cleanroom PanelGEN v1.0")
ws = window.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = window.winfo_screenheight()

x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.configure(background='white')
window.minsize(800, 850)
window.maxsize(800, 850)

menu = Menu(window)
mainmenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=mainmenu)
mainmenu.add_command(label='Generating parameters', command=spec_paneli)
mainmenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=window.destroy)

helpmenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
helpmenu.add_command(label='Info')

window.config(menu=menu)
window.grid_rowconfigure(1, minsize=60)
window.grid_rowconfigure(6, minsize=150)
broButton = Button(master=window, text='Select', style='Wild.TButton', width=16)
broButton.grid(column=2, row=2, padx=45, pady=8)
broButton1 = Button(master=window, text='Select', style='Wild.TButton', width=16)
broButton1.grid(column=2, row=3, padx=45, pady=8)
broButton2 = Button(master=window, text='Generate G-Code', style='Wild.TButton', width=16)
broButton2.grid(column=1, row=7, padx=45, pady=8)
broButton3 = Button(master=window, text='Send to PLC', style='Wild.TButton', width=16)
broButton3.grid(column=1, row=8, padx=45, pady=8)
lbl0 = Label(window, text="Cleanroom PanelGEN v1.0", style='Wild.TLabel', anchor="e", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
lbl0.grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=1, sticky=S)
lbl = Label(window, text="Selected file:   ", style='Wild.TLabel')
lbl.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=W, padx=29)
lbl2 = Label(window, text="Selected location:   ", style='Wild.TLabel')
lbl2.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=W, padx=29, pady=8)
lbl4 = Label(window, text="Select machine:   ", style='Wild.TLabel')
lbl4.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=W, padx=29, pady=8)
lbl4 = Label(window, text="Sheet metal width:   ", style='Wild.TLabel')
lbl4.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=W, padx=29, pady=8)
lbl5 = Label(window, text="FUNCTIONS:", style='Wild.TLabel')
lbl5.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky=W, padx=29, pady=8)
lbl1 = Label(window, text=naziv, style='Wild.TLabel', width=42, anchor="e")
lbl1.grid(column=1, row=2)
lbl3 = Label(window, text=lokacija, style='Wild.TLabel', width=42, anchor="e")
lbl3.grid(column=1, row=3)
combo = Combobox(window, state="readonly")
combo['values'] = ("DECA_NG_paneli", "DECA_NG_zaklopke", "DECA_Gradna_paneli", "Undefined")
combo.current(0)
combo.grid(column=2, row=4, pady=8)
txt1 = Entry(window, width=16, justify='center')
txt1.grid(column=2, row=5)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are lots of problems that prevent us from running your code - missing import statements, missing functions, etc.

Comment: @BryanOakley I understand. There are a couple of images (and a spec file) so I put it all in a folder. Please check the .py code in the link below.  [Code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c1tmq1bopaet2e3/AABAcJ1fwQ8wx-Az56Ckede9a?dl=0)

Comment: Your question needs to directly include the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem. Unless the images are necessary to reproduce the problem, they should be removed from the code. See [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley I edited the code/post to keep it minimal. I just left two windows and buttons with padding.